# Help to identify connector

Tags: connector, identification

Hello I have benen trying to find what this connector is called for a few days. But I can't find it at all. Have been looking at almost all the JST connectors their is. I'm starting to think it's not a connector by JST by now. The connector is used for a scooter motors hall sensors.

Picutre:
female connector:
[image]
male connector:
[image]

Comment: It might help to add what the connector is used for, e.g. fan or servo etc

Comment: looks like Molex. try their site

Comment: The connector is for a electric scooters motor hall sensor.

Answer (score 0):

This is a 6 position 2 row wire to wire connector. I couldn’t find an exact match but I found a female connector that’s similar. Here: https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/925367-3/A106762-ND/2286497

Molex has a variant version: bulky connector. 
But still 6 position two row. Look for part 1510492606 on Molex website.